# my animation is jittery but all settings seem correct

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm working on a project right now and all my renders are super jittery for some reason. I tried to change materials in case the deniosing process was the reason of it but It's still super choppy. I also tried rendering at 30 fps instead of 25 fps but nothing works, I'm not sure what could be the problem. I'm attaching a video so you can see the problem. I would really appreciate the help, I'm in a big rush.

[choppy clip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SIyqpeS9DTPhv15DV0hdS_19VQLm2fet/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I’ve looked at the animation and I’m not seeing any jitteriness. But if there’s something wrong what is your output settings?

Comment: thanks for replying :) Oh Really? could be my monitor, but I can see it in my phone also a bit. this has never happened to me before, I'm quite lost on why. Here are my settings: 

Full HD, 300 samples, compositing denioser and glare, mpeg4, video codec: H264, output quality: perceptualy loseless, encoding speed: good.

Comment: Using a PNG sequence is recommended instead of a video codec. As it keeps better quality and you also can stop the rendering if you see a mistake and then fix it and then resume the rendering. Just change the file format to png and keep the default settings. Then you may want to change your output. Then you can put the frames in a video editor or put in blenders video editor as an image sequence strip. The reason why your video is lagging is that your computer may have low ram. Try closing apps you don’t need then try it. If that doesn’t work, restart your pc and monitor then try again.